# Populate dropdown select button with database array values Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm trying to populate a HTML select dropdown with values of a particular column in the database which is an array in this format **["Red","Yellow","Blue"]**.

I know how to pull the entire product instance for a particular row from DB as a collection and pass it to the view from the controller using;

```
public function index(){
   $product = Product::where('id','=','12')->get();
   return view('product_details', compact('product'));
}
```

Now, for the row I have accessed, I want to populate a select dropdown with the value of the **colours** column for the row with the **id** of 12 which is **["Red","Yellow","Blue"]** which is in the products table in the database. I have no clue on how to achieve that. **Please help out**.

Comment: It seems that you are looking for a mapping function, on which you take the array an turn it into options of a select. Is this correct? I can post a proper answer, but I need to know where your difficult is at: using a `map` function? using functions within `blade` files? making a `select` with HTML?

Comment: Yes @EduardoPacheco, I guess I may need to understand how to use map function and using it in blade. I can work with HTML select pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From all discussion on comments I believe you are unfamiliar with a few concepts of Laravel, its models and blade files. I'll try going through them with you.

#### The Blade File

I like [Karl Hill's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76690242/6506337) to mapping the colors on the [blade file](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade). It did not work because we assumed that you had an array of strings, when you actually have a raw string value representing an array. This is an "issue" with the model, so we'll keep assuming that and fix it, so the current solution should work:

```
<select name="color">
    @foreach ($colors as $color)
        <option value="{{ $color }}">{{ $color }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Another option would be forwarding the whole `$product` to the view, then it would look like this:

```
<select name="color">
    @foreach ($product->colors as $color)
        <option value="{{ $color }}">{{ $color }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

#### The Controller

You also had an issue with finding your model using the `find()` method – this is also an issue with the Model, so we'll stick to it, as it is the best practice on Laravel. Refactoring "bad" or non-standard code is always better than "working around" issues.

```
public function index()
{
    // Product PK will be set to 'id' and the code below **must** work
    $product = Product::findOrFail(12);

    // Colors attribute will be: Array("Red", "Yellow", "Blue")
    $colors = $product->colors;

    // Modern Laravel has a more sophisticated parameter passage functionality.
    // See https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#passing-data-to-components
    return view('product_details', [
        'colors' => $colors,
    ]);
}
```

#### The Model

The main issue seem to be here. In order to use `find` as we stated I need model's default configurations to be true. If `find(12)` does not work with this configurations but `where('id', '=', 12)` does, something wrong and you should debug it until spotting the issue.

```
/**
 * The primary key for the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $primaryKey = 'id';

/**
 * The "type" of the primary key ID.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $keyType = 'int';
```

In order for our `colors` attribute to be properly interpreted as an array, we need to explicitly state it to our model:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be cast.
 *
 * @var array<string, string>
 */
protected $casts = [
    'colors' => 'array',
];
```

#### The Migration

Last but not least, we are expecting your table to be somewhat canonical. So here is a minimalistic migration for our model to work as expected, if your migration has peculiarities, they should be well understood:

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('models', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id()->primary();
        // or: $table->integer('id')->primary();
        $table->array('colors');
        // or: $table->jsonb('colors');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```